# Opacity in C#: form only, not controls

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add transparency to a c# form while keeping controls visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266920/how-can-i-add-transparency-to-a-c-sharp-form-while-keeping-controls-visible)

I am working with C# form with `panel1`.

I have set `Opacity=30%` for `Form1`, But I reflect on `panel1`.

Any help me to by code to set Opacity 30% only on the form, not in `panel1`?

Comment: I'm assuming your setting `Form1.Opacity` to `0.3` ?? Can you put a screenshot of what happens and give a better explanation of what you expect?

Comment: No, it reflect on inner panel

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.  The form's opacity is applied to the whole form, and it's children.  Sorry - not possible with out-of-the-box C# functionality.

Comment: It's also worth adding that some controls' opacity including `Panel` can be changed using the `BackColor` property editing the `Alpha` which takes an integer through 0 to 255 (e.g `panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.White);`). Have a nice day :)