# How to draw a semi-transparent form over a graphical view so the controls are rendered cleanly

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics, transparency

I have a graphical view and I want to overlay a semi-transparent form with a few controls on it such as a TreeView

A bit like this (but with a semi-transparent background):

[image]

I have tried using 2 borderless forms, an underlay with a plain background and an opacity of 60% + an overlay with a TransparentKey and the controls on it. However the text rendering is very bad, especially when the underlay background is pale and the 3D view is dark.

The only approach I can think of is to capture a bitmap of the relevant portion of the 3D View and set that to the background of the form, then hope it renders the TreeView nicely on that.

Is this the best approach? I seems a bit excessive.

This post is what I have used for my basic approach:
[How can I add transparency to a c# form while keeping controls visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266920/how-can-i-add-transparency-to-a-c-sharp-form-while-keeping-controls-visible)

Comment: Even without having a clear understanding of what you need, I'm going to say that winforms is not suitable for this.

Comment: This is a fundamental limitation in the way text is drawn in Windows.  It is *anti-aliased* to improve the appearance of the glyphs.  The most common anti-aliasing technique is ClearType, as used in your screenshot, it adds reddish and blueish pixels at the fringes of the letter, blending it into the background.  That doesn't work when the background is unpredictable, the pixels no longer blend and become very visible, producing very ugly looking type.  Only turning off anti-aliasing is an option to fix that, producing consistently ugly looking text.

Comment: WPF should fare better in such graphics intensive requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Winforms, use WPF instead.